# Magento 2.x I want to check cart price rule is eligible or not without quote, quote item or product

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have a collection of cart price rules. Now I want to validate the rule without a quote, quote item, or any product. If it's valid then I want to do some customize based on it, or not then I want to skip that rule.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
protected $quoteRepository;
protected $ruleData;

public function __construct(
    ...................................................................
    \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomRuleDataFactory $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $ruleData,
    ...................................................................
) {
    ...................................................................
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->ruleData = $ruleData;
    ...................................................................
}

public function execute()
{
    $address = 0;
    $quotesVal = 15
    $quotesData = $this->quoteRepository->get($quotesVal);
    $customerId = (int) $quotesData->getCustomerId();
    $productCount = 0;
    foreach ($quotesData->getAllItems() as $quotesDataKey => $quotesDataVal) {
        $address = $quotesDataVal->getAddress();
        $productCount++;
        break;
    }
    if ($productCount) {
        $address->setCachedItemsAll($quotesData->getAllItems());
        $cartRuleData = $this->ruleData->create()->getCollection();
        foreach ($cartRuleData as $ruleKey => $ruleVal) {
            if ($ruleVal->getConditions()->validate($address)){ // if ($ruleVal->getActions()->validate($address))
                echo "Rule Applied";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***